# Missing H2ConsoleProperties bean in Spring Boot MockMvc test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have spring boot application (mvc, thymeleaf, data jpa, h2) with configuration that permits all users to access h2-console:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    PathRequest.H2ConsoleRequestMatcher h2ConsoleRequestMatcher = PathRequest.toH2Console();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(h2ConsoleRequestMatcher).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(h2ConsoleRequestMatcher));
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    //...
    
    return http.build();
}
```

I also have test where I want to verify, that h2-console is accessible:

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class SecurityApplicationTests {

```
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
void shouldAccessH2Console() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/h2-console"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

When I run test I get the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleProperties' available`

But if I start application from main(), everything works as expected and I can access H2 from the browser.

I would expect that `@SpringBootTest` provides full application context as the `@SpringBootApplication` does

Why the H2ConsoleProperties bean is not created in tests, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on the same issue, got exactly the same exception when running the Spring Boot tests, but when just running the application via main everything works fine.

What solved it for me was to set

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

explicitly in the `application.properties`, as described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database#h2-console. As written there the console is not enable by default and therefore this property has to bet set (Although I could access the console even when the property was not set..).
But I assume that this causes the issue. When the console is not enabled, the autoconfiguration is not available and when also configuring `PathRequest.toH2Console()` in the security configuration the exception occurs.
When explicitly enabling the console, the `H2ConsoleProperties` are also available.

Maybe it helps.